# Protractor: Getting Aria Labels

Tags: protractor

Is there a quick way to access aria-labels for use in Selenium/Protractor tests?

e.g using the `element(by.xxx))` structure?

Comment: element(by.css('aria-label="the label"') ought to do it -- if "it" is accessing the element when you know the aria label. Or are you asking if I have the element, can I find its aria-label (in which case getAttribute should work)

Comment: Thank you Jeremy

Comment: Sure. If it does what you wanted, please let me know and I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
const dropDownButton = element(by.css('[aria-label="arrow_drop_down"]'));
```